# Can new customers be created in QBO API Sandbox

Tags: quickbooks

If I create a customer with DisplayName other than "Bob-Smith" it gives an error: Unknown class Customer. Using v3-php-sdk

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Customer' not found in /home/novaacoustics/public_html/inc/common.php:2247 Stack trace: #0 /home/novaacoustics/public_html/admin/projects/testQuickbooks.php(52): getCustomerObj(Object(QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService), 'Peter Sutcliffe') #1 {main} thrown in /home/novaacoustics/public_html/inc/common.php on line 2247

Customer is created fine if I use API Explorer. I already know the new customer doesn't yet exist because the query:
`$customerArray = $dataService->Query("select * from Customer where DisplayName='" . $customerName . "'");`
returns null.

```
$realmId = $accessTokenObj->setRealmId('4620816365164449490');
    $dataService->updateOAuth2Token($accessTokenObj);
    $customerRef = getCustomerObj($dataService, "John Smith");
```

```
function getCustomerObj($dataService, $customerName = NULL) {

//  $customerName = 'Bob-Smith';
    $customerArray = $dataService->Query("select * from Customer where DisplayName='" . $customerName . "'");
    $error = $dataService->getLastError();
    if ($error) {
        logError($error);
    } else {
        if (is_array($customerArray) && sizeof($customerArray) > 0) {
            return current($customerArray);
        }
    }

    // Create Customer
    echo "creating customer " .$customerName . getGUID();
    $customerRequestObj = Customer::create([
        "DisplayName" => $customerName . getGUID()
    ]);
    $customerResponseObj = $dataService->Add($customerRequestObj);
    $error = $dataService->getLastError();
    if ($error) {
        logError($error);
    } else {
        echo "Created Customer with Id={$customerResponseObj->Id}.\n\n";
        return $customerResponseObj;
    }
}
```

The getGUID() I tried removing and same error. Also the refresh_ and access_tokens are fine, OAuth2 working great.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Thanks for response. Code posted.

Answer (score 0):

OK solved by adding `use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Customer;` at top of file where getCustomerObj function is.